# How to hide the children of the parent on front page but not on full page

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to hide the PowerPress links but not the MP3 player under the excerpt on the front page, while the children are still visible on the full page underneath the player with this code:

```
.entry-summary .p, .powerpress_links.powerpress_links_mp3, .powerpress_subscribe_links {
display: none;
```

}

This keeps the excerpt and player and removes the links beneath the player but it also removes them on the full page. How can I isolate it to just the front page with excerpts?

Comment: Could you please add a jsfiddle code snippet with HTML+CSS code where we can reproduce the problem? Check the point "Help others reproduce the problem" here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here's the JS Bin: https://jsbin.com/viwelufoye/edit?html,css,output As you can see it removes the download and subscribe links below the player. However, if you click on the full post where the same player is displayed at the end, it removed the same links from there as well. I only want the links removed from the "excerpt" on the front page; not the full post.

Comment: WordPress adds classes to the `body` tag depending on what template you're viewing. Look in the inspector, and you should see that you can target things just on the home page by doing `body.home .powerpress_links.powerpress_links_mp3 {}`

Comment: That did it. I was going for the excerpt class in which the powerpress links were a subset class all their own. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body.home .powerpress_links.powerpress_links_mp3 {
    display: none;
```

}

```
body.home .powerpress_links.powerpress_subscribe_links {
    display: none;
```

}